# While I was there

Tags: past-tense, time

Is It correct to say: "While I was there" to make reference not to a place by a organization, like

I joined the army, "while I was there"  ?

I was in a non for profit organization called ABC, while I was in ABC I did communitary work

Comment: Did you mean "not to a place *but to an* organization? "there" referring to either one? You might add some example sentences like what you wrote, with some substitutions for *there* to clarify your question.

Comment: Some grammar points: 1. "not for profit" or "nonprofit"; 2. "community", not "communitary".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under some circumstances, you can use "while I was there... " to describe what you did while you worked for an organization, but it depends on the organization and the context whether it sounds OK.

First, the context: [while](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/while) relates to a period of time. Of the following examples, the first two are OK, because the preceding sentence states or implies that a period of time is involved. The third is not so good because it only specifies a start, and the fourth is not good at all because it does not say anything at all about time.

> I worked for worked for Monsanto about ten years ago. While I was there, I....
>
> I worked for worked for Monsanto between 2005 and 2009. While I was there, I....
>
> I joined Monsanto in 2005. While I was there, I...
>
> I joined Monsanto. While I was there, I...

Concerning the organization: companies (even multinationals like Monsanto) seem to imply a place, so it sounds natural to use **there**. Organizations like UNICEF or the army do not imply a place, so **there** do not sound right. It would be better to say:

> While I was with UNICEF...
>
> While I was in the army...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "During my time at ABC, ..."